# Unable to convert Kafka topic data into structured JSON with Confluent Elasticsearch sink connector

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm building a data pipeline using Kafka. Data flow is as follows: capture data change in mongodb and have it sent to elasticsearch.

[image]

MongoDB

- version 3.6
- shard cluster

Kafka

- Confuent Platform 4.1.0
- mongoDB source connector : debezium 0.7.5
- elasticserach sink connector

Elasticsearch

- version 6.1.0

---

Since I'm still testing, Kafka-related systems are running on single server.

- start zookeepr

  ```
  $ bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
  ```
- start bootstrap server

  ```
  $ bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties
  ```
- start registry schema

  ```
  $ bin/schema-registry-start etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
  ```
- start mongodb source connetor

  ```
  $ bin/connect-standalone \ 
    etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties \ 
    etc/kafka/connect-mongo-source.properties

  $ cat etc/kafka/connect-mongo-source.properties
  >>> 
  name=mongodb-source-connector
  connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
  mongodb.hosts=''
  initial.sync.max.threads=1
  tasks.max=1
  mongodb.name=higee

  $ cat etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties
  >>>
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
  key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
  value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
  internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
  internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
  rest.port=8083
  ```
- start elasticsearch sink connector

  ```
  $ bin/connect-standalone \ 
    etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone2.properties  \ 
    etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/elasticsearch.properties

  $ cat etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/elasticsearch.properties
  >>>
  name=elasticsearch-sink
  connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  tasks.max=1
  topics=higee.higee.higee
  key.ignore=true
  connection.url=''
  type.name=kafka-connect

  $ cat etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone2.properties
  >>>
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
  key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
  value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
  internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.\ 
                        JsonConverter
  internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
  internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
  rest.port=8084
  ```

---

Everything is fine with above system. Kafka connector captures data changes (CDC) and successfully sends it to elasticsearch via sink connector. The problem is that I cannot convert string-type-messaged data into structured data type. For instance, let's consume topic-data after making some changes to mongodb.

```
    $ bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --topic higee.higee.higee --from-beginning | jq
```

Then, I get following result.

```
    "after": null,
      "patch": {
        "string": "{\"_id\" : {\"$oid\" : \"5ad97f982a0f383bb638ecac\"},\"name\" : \"higee\",\"salary\" : 100,\"origin\" : \"South Korea\"}"
      },
      "source": {
        "version": {
          "string": "0.7.5"
        },
        "name": "higee",
        "rs": "172.31.50.13",
        "ns": "higee",
        "sec": 1524214412,
        "ord": 1,
        "h": {
          "long": -2379508538412995600
        },
        "initsync": {
          "boolean": false
        }
      },
      "op": {
        "string": "u"
      },
      "ts_ms": {
        "long": 1524214412159
      }
    }
```

Then, if I go to elasticsearch, I get following result.

```
    {
        "_index": "higee.higee.higee",
        "_type": "kafka-connect",
        "_id": "higee.higee.higee+0+3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "after": null,
          "patch": """{"_id" : {"$oid" : "5ad97f982a0f383bb638ecac"}, 
                       "name" : "higee", 
                       "salary" : 100,
                       "origin" : "South Korea"}""",
          "source": {
            "version": "0.7.5",
            "name": "higee",
            "rs": "172.31.50.13",
            "ns": "higee",
            "sec": 1524214412,
            "ord": 1,
            "h": -2379508538412995600,
            "initsync": false
          },
          "op": "u",
          "ts_ms": 1524214412159
        }
      }
```

One that I want to achieve is something as follows

```
    {
        "_index": "higee.higee.higee",
        "_type": "kafka-connect",
        "_id": "higee.higee.higee+0+3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "oid" : "5ad97f982a0f383bb638ecac",
          "name" : "higee", 
          "salary" : 100,
          "origin" : "South Korea"
         }"
     }
```

---

Some of the options I've been trying and still considering is as follows.

- logstash

  - case 1 : don't know how to parse those characters (/u0002, /u0001)

    - logstash.conf

      ```
      input {
        kafka {
          bootstrap_servers => ["localhost:9092"]
          topics => ["higee.higee.higee"]
          auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
          codec => json {
            charset => "UTF-8"
          }
        }
      }

      filter {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
       }

      output {
        stdout {
          codec => rubydebug
        }
      }
      ```
    - result

      ```
      {
      "message" => "H\u0002�\u0001{\"_id\" : \
          {\"$oid\" : \"5adafc0e2a0f383bb63910a6\"}, \
           \"name\" : \"higee\", \
           \"salary\" : 101, \
           \"origin\" : \"South Korea\"} \
           \u0002\n0.7.5\nhigee \ 
           \u0018172.31.50.13\u001Ahigee.higee2 \ 
           ��ح\v\u0002\u0002��̗���� \u0002\u0002u\u0002�����X",
      "tags" => [[0] "_jsonparsefailure"]
      }
      ```
  - case 2

    - logstash.conf

      ```
      input {
        kafka {
          bootstrap_servers => ["localhost:9092"]
          topics => ["higee.higee.higee"]
          auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
          codec => avro {
            schema_uri => "./test.avsc"
          }
        }
      }

      filter {
        json {
          source => "message"
        }
      }

      output {
        stdout {
          codec => rubydebug
        }
      }
      ```
    - test.avsc

      ```
      {
          "namespace": "example",
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Higee",
          "fields": [
            {"name": "_id", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "salary",  "type": "int"},
            {"name": "origin", "type": "string"}
          ]
       }
      ```
    - result

      ```
      An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<NoMethodError: 
      undefined method `type_sym' for nil:NilClass>, :backtrace=> 
      ["/home/ec2-user/logstash- 
      6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:224:in `match_schemas'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:280:in `read_data'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:376:in `read_union'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:309:in `read_data'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:384:in `block in read_record'", 
      "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:382:in `read_record'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:310:in `read_data'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro- 
      1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:275:in `read'", "/home/ec2- 
      user/logstash-6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/ 
      logstash-codec-avro-3.2.3-java/lib/logstash/codecs/ 
      avro.rb:77:in `decode'", "/home/ec2-user/logstash-6.1.0/ 
      vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-kafka- 
      8.0.2/lib/ logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:254:in `block in 
      thread_runner'", "/home/ec2-user/logstash- 
      6.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-kafka- 
      8.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:253:in `block in 
      thread_runner'"]}
      ```
- python client

  - consumes topic and produce with different topic name after some data manipulation so that elasticsearch sink connector could just consume well-formatted message from python-manipulated topic
  - `kafka` library : wasn't able to decode message

    ```
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                 topics='higee.higee.higee',
                 auto_offset_reset='earliest'
               )

    for message in consumer:
        message.value.decode('utf-8')

    >>> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6: 
        invalid continuation byte
    ```
  - `confluent_kafka` wasn't compatible with python 3

---

Any idea how I can jsonify data in elasticsearch?
Following are sources I searched.

- [mongodb debezium](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/)
- [mongodb event flattening](http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/mongodb-event-flattening/)
- [avro converter](http://debezium.io/docs/faq/#avro-converter)
- [serializing debizium events](http://debezium.io/blog/2016/09/19/Serializing-Debezium-events-with-Avro/)
- [debizum tutorial](http://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/)

Thanks in advance.

---

Some attempts

1) I've changed my connect-mongo-source.properties file as follows to test transformation.

```
    $ cat etc/kafka/connect-mongo-source.properties
    >>> 
    name=mongodb-source-connector
    connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
    mongodb.hosts=''
    initial.sync.max.threads=1
    tasks.max=1
    mongodb.name=higee
    transforms=unwrap     
    transforms.unwrap.type = io.debezium.connector.mongodbtransforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope
```

And following is error log I got. Not yet being comfortable with Kafka and more importantly debezium platform, I wasn't able to debug this error.

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongodb-source-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader expected a string but found '0'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.visitBinDataExtendedJson(JsonReader.java:904)
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.visitExtendedJSON(JsonReader.java:570)
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:145)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:82)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.parse(BsonDocument.java:62)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.apply(UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

2) In this time, I've changed elasticsearch.properties and didn't make a change to connect-mongo-source.properties.

```
$ cat connect-mongo-source.properties

    name=mongodb-source-connector
    connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
    mongodb.hosts=''
    initial.sync.max.threads=1
    tasks.max=1
    mongodb.name=higee

$ cat elasticsearch.properties

    name=elasticsearch-sink
    connector.class = io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=higee.higee.higee
    key.ignore=true
    connection.url=''
    type.name=kafka-connect
    transforms=unwrap
    transforms.unwrap.type = io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope
```

And I got following error.

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key $set
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.throwIfKeyAbsent(BsonDocument.java:844)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.getDocument(BsonDocument.java:135)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.apply(UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

3) changed test.avsc and ran logstash. I didn't get any error message but the outcome wasn't something I was expecting in that `origin`, `salary`, `name` fields were all empty even though they were given non-null values. I was even able to read data through console-consumer properly.

```
$ cat test.avsc
>>>
    {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "MongoEvent",
      "namespace" : "higee.higee",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "_id",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "HigeeEvent",
          "fields" : [ {
            "name" : "$oid",
            "type" : "string"
          }, {
            "name" : "salary",
            "type" : "long"
          }, {
            "name" : "origin",
            "type" : "string"
          }, {
            "name" : "name",
            "type" : "string"
          } ]
        }
      } ]
    }

$ cat logstash3.conf
>>>
    input {
      kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => ["localhost:9092"]
        topics => ["higee.higee.higee"]
        auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
        codec => avro {
          schema_uri => "./test.avsc"
        }
      }
    }

    output {
      stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
      }
    }

$ bin/logstash -f logstash3.conf
>>>
    {
    "@version" => "1",
    "_id" => {
      "salary" => 0,
      "origin" => "",
      "$oid" => "",
      "name" => ""
    },
    "@timestamp" => 2018-04-25T09:39:07.962Z
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to include the data from Mongo itself in your debugging... The patch field is apparently only a string, not an object... Regarding Logstash, `codec => json {` doesn't work for Avro data, and in your Avro codec example, what are `favorite_number` and `favorite_color` supposed to represent?? `$oid` isn't the same as `_id`

Comment: @cricket_007 
1) `favorite_number` and `favorite_color` were `salary` and `origin` respectively. I just copy-pasted different parts. I edited those in above question.
2) what do you mean by actual data from mongodb? patch field represents raw data in string format. That's how I understood and they actually are real data.
3) $oid is object id for each document in mongodb and that's given by mongodb by default. Is there a way I could change/remove that field?

Answer (score 2):

#### Python Client

You **must** use the Avro Consumer, otherwise you will get `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte`

[Even this example will **not** work](https://sonnguyen.ws/simple-example-python-kafka-avro/) because you still need the schema registry to lookup the schema.

[The prerequisites of Confluent's Python Client says it works with Python 3.x](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python#prerequisites)

Nothing is stopping you from using a different client, so not sure why you left it at only trying Python.

#### Logstash Avro Codec

1. JSON Codec cannot decode Avro data. I don't think the json filter following the avro input codec will work either
2. Your Avro schema is wrong - You're missing the `$oid` in place of `_id`
3. There is a difference between "raw Avro" (that includes the schema within the message itself), and Confluent's encoded version of it (which only contains the schema ID in the registry). Meaning, Logstash doesn't integrate with the Schema Registry... at least [not without a plugin](https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry).

Your AVSC should actually look like this

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "MongoEvent",
  "namespace" : "higee.higee",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "_id",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "HigeeEvent",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "$oid",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "salary",
        "type" : "long"
      }, {
        "name" : "origin",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "name",
        "type" : "string"
      } ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

However, [Avro doesn't allow for names starting with anything but a regex of `[A-Za-z_]`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names), so that `$oid` would be a problem.

While I would not recommend it (nor have actually tried it), one possible way to get your JSON-encoded Avro data into Logstash from the Avro console consumer could be use the Pipe input plugin

```
input {
  pipe {
    codec => json
    command => "/path/to/confluent/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic higee.higee.higee --from-beginning" 
  }
}
```

#### Debezium

> note that the `after` value is always a string, and that by convention it will contain a JSON representation of the document

http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/

I think this also applies to `patch` values, but I don't know Debezium, really.

Kafka won't parse the JSON in-flight without the use of a Simple Message Transform (SMT). Reading the documentation you linked to, you should probably [add these to your Connect Source properties](http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/mongodb-event-flattening/#configuration)

```
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope
```

Also worth pointing out, field flattening is on the roadmap - [DBZ-561](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-561)

#### Kafka Connect Elasticsearch

Elasticsearch doesn't parse and process encoded JSON string objects without the use of something like Logstash or its [JSON Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/json-processor.html). Rather, it only indexes them as a whole string body.

If I recall correctly, Connect will only apply an Elasticsearch mapping to top-level Avro fields, not nested ones.

In other words, the mapping that is generated follows this pattern,

```
"patch": {
    "string": "...some JSON object string here..."
  },
```

Where you actually need to be like this - perhaps [manually defining your ES index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/object.html)

```
"patch": {
   "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "properties" {
          "$oid" :  { "type": "text" }, 
          "name" :  { "type": "text" },
          "salary":  { "type": "int"  }, 
          "origin": { "type": "text" }
      },
```

Again, not sure if the dollar sign is allowed, though.

#### Kafka Connect MongoDB Source

If none of the above are working, you could attempt a different connector

- [Option 1](https://github.com/teambition/kafka-connect-mongo)
- [Option 2](https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb)

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your feedback. Configuring debizium connector with following settings didn't work the way I expected. 

        transforms=unwrap
        transforms.unwrap.type = io.debezium.connector.mongodb \ 
                                             transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope

And yes, I read confluent doc that they support Python 3. Once importing libraries, however, I got an exception since some of the codes were written in python2 syntax. Following is an example.

        except NameError, err:

Comment: Instead of manually changing them to python3-compatible code, I just used python2 and it worked. Following is the code

Comment: Please don't post code or long errors into the comments

Comment: I see,they are not at all readable.Then howcould I paste error messages or code blocks?

Comment: Edit your post or if you have solved the problem, post your own answer

Comment: I did post my answer :D

Comment: What's wrong with SMT solution? Also I recommend to do unwrap on the sink connector side. Please check an example - https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-mongodb-smt Also you can check how the unwrapping works when streaming to Elasticsearch http://debezium.io/blog/2018/01/17/streaming-to-elasticsearch/ so you just need to combine both sources mentioned to source from MongoDB to Elasticsearch

Comment: @Jiri  I think you should comment that on the other answer

Comment: @JiriPechanec I missed your comment. I've tried transformation on either side of connectors and I left my logs on my original question. I couldn't paste every trial I've done on this post. Still, however, I'm facing similar errors and still haven't yet figured out how to debug them.

Comment: Biggest obstacle was that I wasn't yet able to understand the syntax and usage of TRANSFORMATIONS. For instance, transformation configuration of sink connector are all different in https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-mongodb-smt/jdbc-sink.json, http://debezium.io/blog/tags/elasticsearch/, and https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/. I know that those three examples are all different environment. Still, I could find right transformation configuration for my use case.

Comment: @GeeYeolNahm Syntax is `"transforms": "<comma separated names>"`, then `"transforms.<name>.type"` is set to `some class` that implements a Transformation. https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-connector-mongodb/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mongodb/transforms/UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.java  Then, when you have more than one transformation, they are applied left to right

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue using python kafka client. Following is new architecture of my pipeline.

[image]

I used python 2 even though Confluent document says that python3 is supported. Main reason was that there were some python2-syntax code. For instance...(Not exactly following line but similar syntax)

```
    except NameError, err:
```

In order to use with Python3 I need to convert above lines into:

```
    except NameError as err:
```

---

That being said, following is my python code. Note that this code is only for prototyping and not for production yet.

#### Consume a message via Confluent Consumer

- code

  ```
  from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer

  c = AvroConsumer({ 
         'bootstrap.servers': '',
         'group.id': 'groupid',
         'schema.registry.url': ''
      })

  c.subscribe(['higee.higee.higee'])

  x = True

  while x:
      msg = c.poll(100)
      if msg:
          message = msg.value()
          print(message)
          x = False

  c.close()
  ```
- (after updating a document in mongodb) let's check `message` variable

  ```
  {u'after': None,
   u'op': u'u',
   u'patch': u'{
       "_id" : {"$oid" : "5adafc0e2a0f383bb63910a6"},
       "name" : "higee",
       "salary" : 100,
       "origin" : "S Korea"}',
   u'source': {
       u'h': 5734791721791032689L,
       u'initsync': False,
       u'name': u'higee',
       u'ns': u'higee.higee',
       u'ord': 1,
       u'rs': u'',
       u'sec': 1524362971,
       u'version': u'0.7.5'},
   u'ts_ms': 1524362971148
   }
  ```

#### manipulate message consumed

- code

  ```
  patch = message['patch']
  patch_dict = eval(patch)
  patch_dict.pop('_id')
  ```
- check `patch_dict`

  ```
  {'name': 'higee', 'origin': 'S Korea', 'salary': 100}
  ```

#### Produce a message via Confluent Producer

```
    from confluent_kafka import avro
    from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer

    value_schema_str = """
    {
       "namespace": "higee.higee",
       "name": "MongoEvent",
       "type": "record",
       "fields" : [
           {
               "name" : "name",
               "type" : "string"
           },
           {
              "name" : "origin",
              "type" : "string"
           },
           {
               "name" : "salary",
               "type" : "int32"
           }
       ]
    }
    """
    AvroProducerConf = {
        'bootstrap.servers': '',
        'schema.registry.url': ''
    }

    value_schema = avro.load('./user.avsc')
    avroProducer = AvroProducer(
                       AvroProducerConf, 
                       default_value_schema=value_schema
                   )

    avroProducer.produce(topic='python', value=patch_dict)
    avroProducer.flush()
```

---

The only thing left is to make elasticsearch sink connector respond to new topic 'python' by setting configuration in following format. Everything remains the same except `topics`.

```
    name=elasticsearch-sink
    connector.class= io.confluent.connect \ 
                     elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=python
    key.ignore=true
    connection.url=''
    type.name=kafka-connect
```

Then run the elasticsearch sink connector and have it checked at elasticsearch.

```
    {
        "_index": "zzzz",
        "_type": "kafka-connect",
        "_id": "zzzz+0+3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "higee",
          "origin": "S Korea",
          "salary": 100
        }
      }
```

Comment: Keep in mind: `eval()` should not be used in Python. Importing json module would be safer. Also, I still believe using a Java Kafka SMT would be the built-in solution to the problem, as this solution isn't failure proof

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @cricket_007's suggestion - use the `io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope` single message transformation. You can read more about SMTs and their benefit's [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've also read part1 and part2. They were helpful in understanding the overall concept. In addition, I've taken a look at two other great documents to get to know deeper on transformation. My problem, at this point however, was that I wasn't able to debug some errors occurred. I'll edit my connect-mongo-source.properties file and paste error messages.

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms and https://www.confluent.io/thank-you/single-message-transformations-not-transformations-youre-looking/

Comment: Here was another try. According to this page http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/mongodb-event-flattening/ on `Configuration` section, it says we need to put that configuration inside sink connector property file. In this time, I got different error message. I'll put that one too on my original question.

Comment: @GeeYeolNahm Is it possible to provide a message from the topic that causes the error?

Comment: @JiriPechanec I've included in my original question. Code block just below "Then, I get following result...." is the message. Will you be able to check it?